# Reduce delay in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

Could you help me decrease the delay in my shiny? I noticed that when I execute my code below, the text: "Access the website:" has a brief delay. All other components appear together, and then the text (Access the website) appears. In another code I have, the delay time is even longer, could you help me solve it?

Thank so much!

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(rdist)
library(geosphere)
library(readxl)
library(shinythemes)

function.cl<-function(df,k){
            
  #cluster
  coordinates<-df[c("Latitude","Longitude")]
  d<-as.dist(distm(coordinates[,2:1]))
  fit.average<-hclust(d,method="average") 
  clusters<-cutree(fit.average, k) 
  nclusters<-matrix(table(clusters))  
  df$cluster <- clusters 

  #database df1  
  df1<-df[c("Latitude","Longitude")]
  df1$cluster<-clusters
  
  #Table to join df and df1
  data_table <- Reduce(merge, list(df, df1))
  
  #Scatter Plot
  suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(ggplot2))
  g<-ggplot(data=df1,  aes(x=Longitude, y=Latitude,  color=factor(clusters))) + geom_point(aes(x=Longitude, y=Latitude), size = 4)
  plotGD<-g

  return(list(
    "Data" =data_table,
    "Plot" = plotGD
  ))
}

ui <- bootstrapPage(
  navbarPage(theme = shinytheme("flatly"), collapsible = TRUE,
             "Cl", 
             
             tabPanel("Solution",
                      fileInput("data", h3("Data import")), 
                      sidebarLayout(
                        sidebarPanel(
                            sliderInput("Slider", h5(""),
                                      min = 2, max = 5, value = 3),
                            uiOutput("tab"),
                            ),
                      
                        mainPanel(
                          tabsetPanel(      
                            tabPanel("Solution", plotOutput("ScatterPlot"))))
                        
                      ))))


server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  v <- reactiveValues(df = NULL)
  observeEvent(input$data, {
    v$df <- read_excel(input$data$datapath)
  })
  
  url <- a("Site", href="http://www.google.com")
  output$tab <- renderUI({
    tagList("Access the website:", url)
  })
  
   Modelcl<-reactive({if (!is.null(v$df)) {
    function.cl(v$df,input$Slider)
   }
   })
   

  output$ScatterPlot <- renderPlot({
    Modelcl()[[2]]
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Unable to replicate.  All GUI items appear instantly for me.  But I don't have `rdist`, `geosphere` or `readxl`.  Your problem might be due to one of them rather than Shiny.

Comment: Please, see this site: https://josesouza.shinyapps.io/test/ It is more noticeable delay.

Comment: Agreed.  Although, for me, the rest if ther sidebar appears, then there's a pause, then the link to the web link in the sidebar AND the main panel appear at the same time.

Comment: @Jose sorry I didn't see that part of the functionality of the application was to adjust the clusters. It makes sense why the code is in inside your application now because you need the result to react to user Input. Apologies and good job (Y)

Comment: Thanks anyway for the code below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in your previous posts you clustering and distance algos are inefficient. Moreover your shiny code is missing.

```
# Install pacakges if they are not already installed: necessary_packages => vector
necessary_packages <- c("ggplot2", "geosphere", "tidyverse")

# Create a vector containing the names of any packages needing installation:
# new_pacakges => vector
new_packages <- necessary_packages[!(necessary_packages %in%
                                       installed.packages()[, "Package"])]

# If the vector has more than 0 values, install the new pacakges
# (and their) associated dependencies:
if(length(new_packages) > 0){install.packages(new_packages, dependencies = TRUE)}

# Initialise the packages in the session:
lapply(necessary_packages, require, character.only = TRUE)

# Data (from previous question): df => data.frame
df <- structure(list(Industries=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19), Latitude = c(-23.8, -23.8, -23.9, -23.9, -23.9,  -23.9, -23.9, -23.9, -23.9, -23.9, -23.9, -23.9, -23.9, -23.9, 
-23.9, -23.9, -23.9, -23.9, -23.9), Longitude = c(-49.6, -49.6, -49.6, -49.6, -49.6, -49.6, -49.6, -49.6, -49.6, -49.6, -49.7, 
-49.7, -49.7, -49.7, -49.7, -49.6, -49.6, -49.6, -49.6)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -19L))

# Store a scalar with the number of clusters for algo: k => integer scalar
k <- 3 

# Define a function returning a list of comprised of a chart object and 
# clustered data.frame: function.cl => function
function.cl <- function(df, k){
  
  # Order the dataframe by Lon and Lat: ordered_df => data.frame
  ordered_df <- 
    df %>% 
    arrange(., desc(Longitude), desc(Latitude))  
  
  # Matrix of co-ordinates: coordinates => matrix
  coordinates <-   
    ordered_df %>% 
    select(Longitude, Latitude) %>% 
    as.matrix()
  
  # Generate great circle distances between points and Long-Lat Matrix: d => data.frame
  d <- data.frame(Dist = c(0, distVincentyEllipsoid(coordinates)))
  
  # Segment the distances into groups: cluster => factor 
  d$Cluster <- factor(cumsum(d$Dist > (quantile(d$Dist, 1/k))) + 1)

  # Merge with base data: clustered_df => data.frame
  data_table <- cbind(ordered_df, d)
  
    #Scatter Plot: plotGD => plot object
  plotGD <- ggplot(data = data_table,  aes(
    x = Longitude,
    y = Latitude,
    color = factor(Cluster))) +
    geom_point(aes(x = Longitude, y = Latitude), size = 4)
  
  # Create and define the return object: list => .GlobalEnv()  
  return(list(
    "Data" = data_table,
    "Plot" = plotGD
  ))
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, do you think the delay to appear the message is due to the code that generates the cluster?

Comment: @Jose see comment above.

Comment: Additionally the access the website url leads me to google pretty much instantly, so no I don't think there is much you can do to optimise that.

Comment: Hi Hello_friend, do you have any idea? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62942732/map-from-sfnetwoks-package-in-r